# One Way SSL Implementation in .net - Need assistance

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate

We need to Implement one way ssL connection to a remote server . We have been given the APi end point and also the public key certificate.

We are trying to use the HttpClient to connect but it seems this approach requires us to have a private key as well.

Is there an example one way SSL implementation example in .net that we can refer

Comment: Does the certificate contain both the public and private key?

Comment: They give you the certificate so when your app verifies the server side certificate it can know what is the proper one. That's not a certificate you should pass to `HttpClient`. Some examples, https://www.meziantou.net/custom-certificate-validation-in-dotnet.htm

Comment: @jdweng no - the cert has only the public key. Its mentioned that one way SSL needs only public key

Comment: @LexLi i hv tried what you suggested . Still getting error - request was aborted . Could not establish TLS/SSL (used TLS 1.2) as required by server

Comment: Then that's a different issue and you need to use tools like Wireshark to analyze TLS handshake packets for hints.